# how can i use the value of the field to form another field in a form?

Tags: jquery, forms, yii2

I want to use value of a field store id to form  field product list which are from that store by using and the input in the where clause for the product field I end up getting error and its not clear how I can achieve it please help. should I include my controller code and model code or this is enough?

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <div class="container-fluid row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'ouput_store_id')->dropDownList(
                arrayHelper::map(Store::find()
                ->where(['manager_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
                ->all(),'store_id','name'),
                ['prompt' => 'Select Store', 'id' => 'output',
                 'class' => 'form-control text-center']
            ) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'product_id')->dropDownList(
                arrayHelper::map(Product::find()->where('store_id' => $model->output_store_id)
                ->all(),'product_id','product_name'),
                ['prompt' => 'Select product', 'id'=> 'product',
                 'class' => 'form-control text-center']
            ) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: You've tagged jQuery yet shown us PHP. The two are unrelated. jQuery acts on HTML. Also take the time to capitalize and punctuate your sentences. Show your readers some respect.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how to best use this site.

Comment: Just use a JQuery to get a field value based on the type and id of the field.

Comment: You need [dependent dropdown](https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop).